# Oracle IMPDP not importing rows

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, impdp

I am trying to import one table from a full DB export but the table I want will not import the rows. If I try another table then the rows import fine!

Using Oracle 11.2.0.4 in Windows 2008 R2

The export was successful :

```
Job "BKUP_USER"."EXPFULL" successfully completed at Wed Mar 28 11:25:10 2018 elapsed 0 00:54:55
```

And the import was also successful (from a logging point of view) :

```
;;; 
Import: Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production on Wed Oct 10 12:37:58 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.
;;; 
Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
Master table "BKUP_USER"."IMPDOC" successfully loaded/unloaded
Starting "BKUP_USER"."IMPDOC":  bkup_user/******** parfile=ajrlead.par 
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/TABLE/TABLE
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/TABLE/TABLE_DATA
. . imported "ROBERTKING"."WWV_DOCUMENT$"                89.78 GB       0 out of 107278 rows
. . imported "ROBERTKING"."WWV_HELP$"                    689.4 KB     284 rows
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/TABLE/GRANT/OWNER_GRANT/OBJECT_GRANT
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/TABLE/INDEX/INDEX
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/TABLE/INDEX/FUNCTIONAL_INDEX/INDEX
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/TABLE/CONSTRAINT/CONSTRAINT
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/TABLE/INDEX/STATISTICS/INDEX_STATISTICS
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/TABLE/INDEX/STATISTICS/FUNCTIONAL_INDEX/INDEX_STATISTICS
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/TABLE/STATISTICS/TABLE_STATISTICS
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/TABLE/TRIGGER
Job "BKUP_USER"."IMPDOC" successfully completed at Wed Oct 10 12:38:05 2018 elapsed 0 00:00:07
```

Just that it does not import the rows for the table I want!:

> 0 out of 107278 rows

My import parameter file :

```
SCHEMAS=e_agent_site
REMAP_SCHEMA=e_agent_site:robertking
DUMPFILE=AJRLEAD:FULL%U.dmp
LOGFILE=AJRLEAD:doc_restore.log
JOB_NAME=IMPDOC
TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION=APPEND
CONTENT=ALL
INCLUDE=TABLE:"IN ('WWV_HELP$', 'WWV_DOCUMENT$')"
```

I've some mentions around sysdba causing issues, the file was not exported using sysdba but I have trued running the import as sys as sysdba and get the same issue

Any ideas???

Comment: There can be numerous problems. Here are few that are coming to my mind right away:
1. was the export done with compress=all option?
2. was the table paritioned and you are importing to non-partition db?

Comment: There was no compression specified so whatever the default is
No partitioning of the table

expdp bkup_user/[password] FULL=Y DUMPFILE=full%U.dmp FILESIZE=2G PARALLEL=1 LOGFILE=expfull.log JOB_NAME=expfull DIRECTORY=dpump_dir1

Comment: This is less of a problem now as I have managed to recover the data from another non expdp backup of the database